# Is it possible to make a parse.com database available for public download/export?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a database on parse.com available publicly for download.  I have a scraper running on Google App Engine that grabs data from Kickstarter and saves it to Parse, and I want to make it available for researchers, hobbyists, etc.

Comment: This is probably a better question for parse.com.  Their policy can change in time which will make any answers here unuseful.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite broad in terms of how you want the data to be "available" to the "public".

But in general, yes this is absolutely possible. Just write a parse cloud code function that returns the data you want. Then have your frontend call that function, and your frontend will do the interpretation of how to display it (or structure it for download). This method returns JSON to be handled by the frontend.

If you want to make it available for file download (e.g. in the form of a table or something), you can use the parse rest api.

https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#files

The procedure is to upload it, and the callback returns the url where it can be accessed. The file is public to anyone that knows the url to the file.